# "Request of modification" vs "modification request"

Tags: word-usage

As the title says, which one is better?  The entire phrase should be something like

> Any **[request of modification/modification request]** should be sent to the Manager first

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Request for modification*

or

*Request to modify*

or

*Modification Request*  (is a little more ambiguous than the above two)

Request of modification is incorrect usage.